# Is $f*\mu(x)=\int f(xy)dy$?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

I am only recently familiarizing myself with basic harmonic analysis so pardon me if my question seems odd. I have a locally compact abelian topological group $G$. For $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ I have the definition $$f*\mu(x)=\int \Delta(y^{-1})f(xy^{-1})dy$$
And I have the identity $$\int f(x^{-1})\Delta(x^{-1})dx=\int f(x)dx$$
So with these two, wouldn't we get $f*\mu(x)=\int f(xy)dy$ ?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the notation here--are $\mu$, and $dx$ both denoting Haar measure, or is $\mu$ something else? Also, since the group is abelian, the modular function $\Delta$ is identically $1$.

Comment: Assuming that $\mu$ and $dx$ *are* both Haar measure, which seems likely, then your conclusion is correct (assuming $f$ is integrable, so that the integrals in question are well-defined). In fact, you can go further and conclude that $f \ast \mu \equiv \int f \, d\mu$.

Comment: @Jason Yes, I could have written $dx$ and $dy$ as $d\mu(x)$ and $d\mu(y)$ where $\mu$ is a Haar measure

Comment: @Jason $f*\mu$ is a function but $\int fd\mu$ appears to be an integral?

Comment: Sure - writing $f \ast \mu \equiv \int f \, d\mu$ means that the function $f \ast \mu$ is identically equal to the number $\int f \, d\mu$ (since an integral in this setting evaluates to a number). That is, for all $x \in G$ we have $f \ast \mu(x) = \int f \, d\mu$.

Comment: @Jason Oh, is it assuming that the group is Abelian?

Comment: Right, in the post it says the topological group is locally compact and abelian.